# About "bind" in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, bind

Here is the code:

```
vector<int> vec{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
string str("123456");
auto result = find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), bind(check_size, str, _1));
```

It doesn't pass `vec` to `_1` like this: (but the code can run correctly)

```
auto checkn = bind(check_size, str, _1);
checkn(vec);
```

Does it mean that the `_1` can auto receive the `vec`? I'm quite confused about this.

Comment: `find_if` doesn't pass `vector` but the elements of `vector` to it.

Comment: Thank you! I was confusing that how bind knows what _1 is.

Comment: `_1` is just a placeholder declared by `bind`. What argument will be passed in is determined by the caller, i.e. `find_if` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a callable object, like for example a function, you can make another callable object with **[`std::bind()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/)** by binding some of its parameters to fixed values and leave other parameters to be provided later.  The latter are identified with [placeholders](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/placeholders/) named `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, etc.

In your example, and supposing that `check_size()` is a function taking two arguments,  `bind(check_size, str, _1)` would return a callable object having one parameter.  This callable would return for any parameter `x` the value `check_size("123456",x)`.

When used in your `find_if` context, `bind(check_size, str, _1)` would hence be called for each `int` item in the vector until the result is true.

In the second case, the callable would be called with vec as parameter.  This may or may not compile, depending on how `check_size()` is defined.